# Eclipse Versioning Project

Tags: java, eclipse

We develop same project with my colleague. We do not use any team programs. Thefore, when i editting same class which is editting by my colleague at the same time but as i said there is no plugin like team development. Same project is developing two different eclipses. I want to do that to version my project which is located in my eclipse workspace. Then, my colleague also version his project and i want to combine them in my or his eclipse. Is there any plugins or eclipse function to do that? I hope i clearly explain what i want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Learn and use a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), such as Subversion or Git. There are plugins for almost any version control system for Eclipse.

For example, there's [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), an Eclipse plugin for working with [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), or [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) for working with [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: I'd like to throw in Mercurial. It's a distributed version control system like GIT but 'easier'. My advice is to skip Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git`](http://git-scm.com).

It's a distributed code versioning system, and will help you in what you want to achieve. It does not need a central repository, so you do not need any *server* for it, you can just synchronize your private repositories with your colleague.

For integration with Eclipse, use [`EGit`](http://www.eclipse.org/egit)

If it's going to be open-source, you may consider creating an account on [github.com](http://github.com) and hosting your repo there. Github gives some first-class tools when working with `git`.

Answer (score 1):

You use Github which works very finely and may be better than SVN in many cases.It has very handy tools like git gui and git pull commands which works very finely and without any complexity

[Here](https://github.com/) is its official site

Answer (score 0):

You should use a versioning system but if you do this:

> when i editting same class which is editting by my colleague at the
>   same time

You will still have an issue as each will code in its own version of the file and you will have to carefully merge the changes (my experience is with Clearcase)